# Is there a way to check if a button was checked in the main html file and do something with it on another html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have 2 HTML pages...The main page is about a user choosing a category and based on the category he chose I wanna display something to the other HTML file i have is a quiz app I'm trying to build...once the user chooses a category I wanna display the first question from that category and then start iterating through other questions

Comment: Investigate passing a parameter in the url (?question=1 for example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need persistent data storage, If you're using a backend you can save its state in the DB, session storage or even as a cookie. If you don't you can use local storage to preserve the state of the check bottom on one page and act based on it on the other.